# Excluding certain aspects in sql

Tags: sql-server

I was hoping someone could help me.

I have the following 5 tables:

### tblCustomer

```
CustomerID   CustomerName   
 -------     ------------
   1         ABC Bank     
   2         Chase Bank
```

### tblOrderType

```
OrderTypeID    OrderTypeName   
 ----------    ------------
   1           Assignment     
   2           LienRelease
```

### tblActivity

```
ActivityID        ActivityName   
 ----------       ------------
   1              Received     
   2              Keyed
   3              Printed
   4              Delivered To Cusotmer
```

### tblOrder

```
OrderID        CustomerID      OrderTypeID   LoanNumber
 ----------    ------------    -----------   ----------
   1           1                1            45584565
   2           1                1            45566856
   3           1                1            45565584
   4           1                1            45588545
```

### tblOrderActivity

```
OrderID        ActivityID    ActivityDate
 ----------    -----------   ----------
   1           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   1           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM  
   1           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM 
   1           4             2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM  
   2           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   3           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   3           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM
   3           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM
   3           4             2007-04-16 4:14:00 PM
   4           1             2007-04-16 8:34:00 AM
   4           2             2007-04-16 9:22:00 AM
   4           3             2007-04-16 9:51:00 AM
```

The information has been changed for protection purposes. So say I need to be able to list all Assignment orders that have a “Received” activity but not a “Delivered” activity for ABC Bank and I need to return CustomerName, CustomerID, LoanNumber, and “received date” (Activity Date for received). I have been able to get everything done, however, I am unable to remove any files that have not had an Activity of "Delivered". Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT tblCustomer.CustomerName, tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblOrder.LoanNumber, (tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate) AS [received date]
FROM tblOrderActivity (NOLOCK)

INNER JOIN tblOrder (NOLOCK)
ON tblOrderActivity.OrderID = tblOrder.OrderID

INNER JOIN tblCustomer (NOLOCK)
ON tblOrder.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID

INNER JOIN tblOrderType (NOLOCK)
ON tblOrder.OrderTypeID = tblOrderType.OrderTypeID

INNER JOIN tblActivity (NOLOCK)
ON tblActivity.ActivityID = tblOrderActivity.ActivityID

WHERE tblOrderType.OrderTypeName = 'Assignment' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT [OrderID] FROM [tblOrderActivity] WHERE tblActivity.ActivityName = 'Received')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT [OrderID] FROM [tblOrderActivity] WHERE tblActivity.ActivityName = 'Delivered To Customer')

GROUP BY tblCustomer.CustomerName, tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblOrder.LoanNumber, tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate;
```

And my results are below

```
CustomerName   CustomerID      LoanNumber    received date
 ----------    ------------    -----------   ----------
 ABC Bank      1               45565584      2007-04-16 08:34:00.000
 ABC Bank      1               45566856      2007-04-16 08:34:00.000
 ABC Bank      1               45584565      2007-04-16 08:34:00.000
 ABC Bank      1               45588545      2007-04-16 08:34:00.000
```

Comment: Why are you using the ActivityName field in the where clause instead of the OrderTypeID?  This can lend itself to typos.  In fact, there's a typo in your question:  The ActivityName in your table listing contains "Delivered to Cusotmer" and in your select statement is "Delivered to Customer".

Comment: that was a mistype, let me correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Not the most efficient t-sql in the world, but the schema doesn't help much.  May need to alias the tables in the main query to make it more readable and ensure the subqueries work properly (at least that's what I usually do).

This should return all received records that do not have a delivery

```
SELECT tblCustomer.CustomerName, tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblOrder.LoanNumber, (tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate) AS [received date]
FROM tblOrderActivity (NOLOCK)

INNER JOIN tblOrder (NOLOCK)
ON tblOrderActivity.OrderID = tblOrder.OrderID

INNER JOIN tblCustomer (NOLOCK)
ON tblOrder.CustomerID = tblCustomer.CustomerID

INNER JOIN tblOrderType (NOLOCK)
ON tblOrder.OrderTypeID = tblOrderType.OrderTypeID

INNER JOIN tblActivity (NOLOCK)
ON tblActivity.ActivityID = tblOrderActivity.ActivityID

WHERE tblOrderType.OrderTypeName = 'Assignment' 

AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [tblOrderActivity] WHERE OA.ActivityID = 4 AND OA.OrderID = tblOrder.OrderID)  --Delivered Excluded
AND tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = 1  --Received Only
```

Comment: Neither of these work. It is giving 12 rows in the results. Should only be returning 2 rows

Comment: Ah, missed that one of the return fields is tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate.  This will cause each record to be distinct.  Will need to do the group by with an aggregate clause (assuming you'll want the most recent date, but you can change that).  I'll adjust my answer

Comment: Essentially, I only want the Received Activity Type for only the Orders that have not been delivered. So it should reflect just 2 Orders and the time they were received

Comment: one more quick question. Why is it required to basically SELF JOIN tblOrder to itself? Just want to make sure I understand for future reference

Comment: Good observation!  It's actually not necessary since OrderID is already in tblOrderActivity.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblOrder
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'r' AS r, tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate, tblActivity.ActivityName, tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    FROM tblOrderActivity
    JOIN tblActivity ON tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID 
        AND tblActivity.ActivityName = 'Received'
) AS Received ON tblOrder.OrderID = Received.OrderID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'd' AS d, tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate, tblActivity.ActivityName, tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    FROM tblOrderActivity
    JOIN tblActivity ON tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID 
        AND tblActivity.ActivityName = 'Delivered To Cusotmer'
) AS Delivered ON tblOrder.OrderID = Delivered.OrderID
WHERE Delivered.ActivityDate IS NULL
```

or like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblOrder
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'r' AS r, tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate, tblActivity.ActivityName, tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    FROM tblOrderActivity
    JOIN tblActivity ON tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID 
        AND tblActivity.ActivityID IN (SELECT ActivityID FROM tblActivity WHERE tblActivity.ActivityName = 'Received')
) AS Received ON tblOrder.OrderID = Received.OrderID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'd' AS d, tblOrderActivity.ActivityDate, tblActivity.ActivityName, tblOrderActivity.OrderID
    FROM tblOrderActivity
    JOIN tblActivity ON tblOrderActivity.ActivityID = tblActivity.ActivityID 
        AND tblActivity.ActivityID IN (SELECT ActivityID FROM tblActivity WHERE tblActivity.ActivityName = 'Delivered To Cusotmer')
) AS Delivered ON tblOrder.OrderID = Delivered.OrderID
WHERE Delivered.ActivityDate IS NULL
```

trim it down to just the columns you want of course

Comment: Bummer, sorry, when i tried it I got back just 2 rows.